# Using LM393 Sound sensor to detect sound frequency

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, iot

I am using sound sensor module LM393 to detect the sound frequency of snoring in setup with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ which occurs at around 300-500Hz. The scope of my mini project is to detect the sound at that particular range and then send it to firebase realtime database from which i can later utilize on my web applications front end. Currently the LM393 sensor detects any sound which has been calibrated using its built in function and sends the message to firebase.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import datetime
from firebase import firebase
import urllib2, urllib, httplib
import json
import os 
from functools import partial

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#GPIO SETUP
channel = 24
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('....', None)

def update_firebase():
    print('Sound Detected')
    data = {"Sound": "Sound Detected"}
    firebase.post('/sensor/sound', data)

def update_firebase2():
    print('Sound Detected')
    data2={"Sound": "Sound Not Detected"}
    firebase.post('/sensor/sound',data2)


def callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(channel):
            update_firebase()
    else:
            update_firebase2()

GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=300)  # let us know when the pin goes HIGH or LOW
GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, callback)  # assign function to GPIO PIN, Run function on change

# infinite loop
while True:
        callback(channel)
        #sleepTime = int(sleepTime)
        sleep(10)
```

Comment: Sound classification is a hard problem, but at the very least, you'd want an actual analog audio input.  Look into either a USB "soundcard" (they are usually mono input, even if stereo or 5.1 output) or some sort of PI soundcard that goes on the GPIO connector.  But consider sorting out the algorithm on your PC or laptop first, and only moving it to the pi once it is debugged and proven.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use lm393 sensor for detecting the frequency of the sound. So no matter what software you churn up, detecting the frequency is not possible. However, by changing the potentiometer value, you can alter the range or the threshold in which you can detect the sound.

> This sensor only recognizes the availability of sound cannot identify
>   the size of the sound or the specific frequencies of sound.

Reference:https://robu.in/product/lm393-sound-detection-sensor-module-black/

And to complicate your problem is the problem that you are trying to detect a snore which is a mixture of sounds. It is not a simple sine wave but will be a complex function. If you want to detect the frequency of a sine wave it would have been a simple problem. Natural sounds are complex and are a mixture of frequencies that change over the duration of the sound. For that you need Fourier Transformation and something called an [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform).

You will have to “break” the sound into individual frequencies and measure or visualize each individual frequency.

Comment: Thank you for your informative reply. In this link he utilized LM393 to detect whistle sound only. May i know if this can be possible to detect snoring.

Comment: https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-whistle-detector-switch